# Procedimiento almacenado invocando dll

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo que crear un procedimiento almacenado que recibe un parámetro y devuelve otro. Dentro del procedimiento declaro una variable y le doy valor con un select. Posteriormente con la variable de entrada y la obtenida del select invoco a una dll. Tengo esto, pero no se llega a crear el SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpInvoke]
(@funcion NVARCHAR (MAX), 
@salida REAL OUTPUT)
AS 
declare @url as nvarchar (max) = SELECT TOP 1 url FROM Config
EXTERNAL NAME [User.BBDD.SQLServer].[StoredProcedures].[SpInvoke]
GO
```

Comment: ¿Has creado el assembly en sql server antes de invocar a la librería?

Comment: Sí, el assembly está creado. Sin la linea de "declare" sí que funciona.

Comment: ¿La consola de sql lanza algún error?

Comment: Sí, el siguiente: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SpInvoke, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXTERNAL'.

Comment: Probá con encerrar entre paréntesis `declare @url as nvarchar (max) = (SELECT TOP 1 url FROM Config)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la documentación la única línea de código que es permitida con un SP que llame a una dll es EXTERNAL, por lo que no se puede usar otra instrucción SQL dentro.

Te recomiendo que hagas lo siguiente. La variable `url` inicializala con el valor de la consulta afuera del SP y luego enviala como parámetro. De esta manera podrás llamar a la dll con ese valor. Algo así:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpInvoke]
(@funcion NVARCHAR (MAX),
 @url  nvarchar (max),
 @salida REAL OUTPUT)
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [User.BBDD.SQLServer].[StoredProcedures].[SpInvoke]
GO

/*Antes de llamar al SP*/
declare @url as nvarchar (max) = (SELECT TOP 1 url FROM Config)
Excute PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpInvoke] @funcion, @url,...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Estaba intentando hacerlo todo en un SP pero si no es posible, lo divido.